# Apple Magic Trackpad - Avoid accidental cursor movement

Tags: imac, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I am in the process of switching from a 13" MacBook Pro to an iMac which has external Apple wireless keyboard and Trackpad, and I am struggling with the transition due to Trackpad.

I tried using the Trackpad by placing it physically below the keyboard (like a MacBook Pro) to make it more similar to the MacBook Pro experience, but it didn't help much due to its weight and surface which is double the size of MacBook. I also tried to use it on the right side but I still touch it and move the cursor.

I need to mention that I do have the Tap-to-Click enabled as I am used to it. I do not like making a physical press to register the click and would like to leave Tap-to-Click enabled.

Is there something I can do to avoid these very soft accidental touches that ruin my text typing? Like a tool to lower its sensitive area to the centre of the Trackpad and make it insensitive towards its edges.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I quite understand your description/situation, especially if you're used to the trackpad on the MacBook. I've never used the Magic Trackpad, so I'm failing to see how that experience would be much different, aside from the freedom to place it wherever. If you could try to elaborate a little, these are the questions I was left with: If you have it on the right side and you're typing with your keyboard, how are you accidentally touching the trackpad? Or in general? How is that even possible? It's also lost on me how the edges of the trackpad would be your problem area?

Comment: @Joonas whenever you would be putting the trackpad you will eventually touch it by accident and if you happen to have the touch-click option enabled,... you are doomed to move your cursor somewhere else.

Comment: I don't quite understand yet. I mean it's meant to be touched, but doing that accidentally while typing... How do you manage that? Like you try to press Enter but you end up missing it and hitting the trackpad? Couldn't you place it a bit farther away?

Comment: When you press Return key with your ring finger your pinky will likely touch the trackpad before or after you hit the key. This question is aimed for trackpad users, you need to have one to understand how annoying sensible it can be. I guess most users ditched it in favour of magic mouse which does not have the same issue.

Comment: You might be right. I feel like I would place the trackpad like perhaps 1 trackpad width to the right of my keyboard. I do remember when I started using the magic mouse (gen 1), I used to have this issue where I would trigger scrolling when I would grab the mouse or release my grip. After using it for long enough I learned to be more careful about that. Based on what you've said so far I think I may be able to give you an answer that will help you.

Comment: @sorin did you ever get a solution that worked well? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe a third party app called [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) could help you out. It costs around $8, but it does have a 45 day trial.

I'd say for the most part this app is for customizing gestures or just setting hotkeys and stuff like that, but it has pretty robust settings for alleviating these types of trackpad issues.

The trackpad settings can be found from the main window on the top right. Though you may have to enable advanced settings on the top left of the window before you can see the trackpad settings.

Screenshots of every single page of these trackpad settings:

*I highlighted settings that may help you the most...*

[image]